# Control resize on finger touch in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, c#-3.0

I want to resize control on finger touch in windows phone 7 appl.Can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you're trying to do. What type of control are you trying to resize? And by touch, do you mean 'tap' or do you mean 'pinch' ?

Comment: I want to resize control like button.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that what you are looking for is Control Tilt effect. Tilt effect is the effect of slight move in the plane projection of controls when they are touched.

You can learn tilt effect and how to use it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/03/23/tilt-effect-for-windows-phone-controls.aspx